# Fill Field When All Checkboxes Toggled Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an expenditures subform in Access 2010 that lists the predicted costs associated with the project for each year. Most projects only have one year, but some have more than one. Each cost has a Final checkbox next to it that should be checked when the amount is confirmed, ie. at the end of each year.

It basically looks something like this:

```
Year    |   Cost    |   Final
--------+-----------+--------------------
2017    |   $100    |   [checked box]
2018    |   $200    |   [unchecked box]
        |          |   [unchecked box]
```

I have another field outside the table, FinalCost, that adds up everything in the Cost field. Right now, it fills in the amount from any year which has a checked Final box. That should *only* be filled when *all* the Final boxes are checked.

Ex. Right now, it should show nothing even though Final for 2017 is checked. When 2018 is checked, it should show $300. Instead, it shows $100 even though there's still an empty checkbox.

This is the code for this form.

```
Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
Dim rs1, rs2 As Recordset
Dim sql, sql2 As String

sql = "SELECT Sum(Amount) as Final From Expenditures " & _
"Where ProjNo = '" + Me.ProjNo + "' And Final = True Group by ProjNo"

sql2 = "SELECT FinalExpenditure From ActivityCash " & _
"Where ProjNo = '" + Me.ProjNo + "'"

Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset, dpinconsistent)
Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql2, dbOpenDynaset, dpinconsistent)

If rs1.RecordCount > 0 Then
If rs2.RecordCount > 0 Then
Do While Not rs2.EOF
    rs2.Edit
    rs2!FinalExpenditure = rs1!Final
    rs2.Update
    rs2.MoveNext
Loop
End If
End If

rs2.Close
rs1.Close
Set rs1 = Nothing
Set rs2 = Nothing

End Sub
```

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

EDIT: When the last box is checked, a new row is automatically added with an untoggled checkbox but no information.

Comment: If the `Count(*) WHERE Final = False > 0` then don't fill it.

Comment: Well, you said **"That should only be filled when all the Final boxes are checked"**.. So if 1 or more records value for `Final` are `False`, then don't supply a value.

Comment: Where should I put this? Above `sql=`?

Comment: Well, first - does that sound like it solves your problem? If so, I'll throw it in an answer.

Comment: That does look like it might do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the statement beginning with `sql = ...` with this:

```
sql = "SELECT SUM(e1.Amount) AS Final " & _
    " FROM Expenditures AS e1 " & _
    " WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM Expenditures e2 WHERE e2.Final=0 AND e1.ProjNo = e2.ProjNo) " & _
    " AND e1.ProjNo = '" & Me.ProjNo & "'"
```

This query will return data only if there are all expeditures for the project marked as final. As you check for `rs1.RecordCount > 0` there will be no update if this query returns no records.

Comment: When I try and run this, it gives me an error at Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset, dpinconsistent): "Runtime Error 3061: Too few parameters. Expected 1."

Comment: That is a sure sign there is a literal in the sql that refers to a table-field that does not exist. Please double check that the fields "Amount", "Final" and "ProjNo" exist in your table "Expenditures".

Comment: I don't know, I just repasted this bit of code over what I had and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

So, before `sql`, I would verify that *all* records have `True` in your `Final` field.

To do that, let's just return a `COUNT()` of (any) records that have `Final = False`, and we can then decide to do what we want.

So, something like,

```
Dim Test as Integer

test = DCount("*", "YourTableName", "Final = False AND ProjNo = " & Me.ProjNo &"")

If test > 0 Then
    'Don't fill the box
Else
    'Fill the box, everything is True
    'Read through your recordsets or whatever else you need to do
End If
```

**To use a query**, we essentially need to replicate the `Dcount()` functionality.
To do this, we need another `Recordset` variable, and we need to check the value of the `Count()` field from our query.

Create a query that mimicks this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) As CountTest
FROM YourTable 
HAVING Final = False 
   AND ProjNo = whateverprojectnumberyou'reusing
```

Save it, and remember that query's name.

Much like the `DCount()`, we need to make this "check" determine the route of your code.

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("YourQuery'sNameHere")

If rst!CountTest > 0 Then
    'They are not all Checked (aka True)
    Else
    'Supply the value to the FinalCost
End If
Set rst = Nothing
```

Comment: Well, you said you only want it to be filled if `test < 1`, aka if there are no records where `Final = False`. So I would put all code in between `Else and End If` (I stated that in my comments). Otherwise, I would set the value of your field to `""` or whatever *you want to do* for it.

Comment: It's still giving me the same result. I wrote the first part as `If Test > 0 Then
FinalExpenditure = ""`. Maybe this is wrong? I'm not really much of a VBA programmer.

Comment: Yeah. I guess I should have mentioned that. There's an Expenditures table that has all the info for all the projects. The form for each individual project has an Expenditures subform, with the expenditures for just the one project listed. If that makes any sense. Maybe I need to specify that I'm referring to the table in the subform?

Comment: Exactly. Our DCount works, but we need to narrow it down just a little more to make sure we aren't examining things that we aren't concerned with, so if it's `ProjNo` or some other field, we need to add that as well. Do you think that will solve your problem?

Comment: Okay, create a query that mimics the `DCount` and run it. Something like, `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable HAVING Final = False AND ProjNo = whateverprojectnumberyou'reusing`

Comment: I'm going to delete some of my earlier comments to clean this up, I suggest you do the same so we can have some clear direction to what we've derived. I have to go, but I think you can get it working.

Comment: Well, the DCount should be identical to that query. There's something amiss with it. I gotta run, but if `ProjNo` is a 'Text' datatype, you'll need to change it to `'" & Me.ProjNo &"'`. I hope I helped a little bit

Comment: I'm trying to use a `Dlookup` to pull the value from the query table, since the query worked, but it's giving me a run-time error 2471: The expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error: '[Me].[ProjNo]'. The Dlookup I'm using is `Countboxes = DLookup("[TBoxes]", "qryFinalExpenditure", "[ProjNo] = '" & Me.ProjNo& "'")`

Comment: You need a space before the second `&`

Comment: Is the `ProjNo` field in your table a `Number` or `Text`?

Comment: It seems like it can't find your `ProjNo` value then, maybe? This shouldn't be this difficult

Comment: That likely means are refering `Me.ProjNo` in your query incorrectly, or it just doesn't exist in the current scope.

Comment: I think I was trying to grab `ProjNo` from the wrong place. I grabbed if from the `Expenditures` table and it doesn't give me an error anymore. But it doesn't fill in the `FinalExpenditures` field when all the boxes are checked.

Comment: Okay, well what are the results you're getting from the query then? I can't help you along every step of the way, you need to do *some* debugging here, Nothing should have changed except we are either loading the results like you had been previously, or we are not. That's it. So either the query returns a count > 0 or < 1 and we make decisions based off of that. If your old code worked, it should still work as long as you place it in the `Else` statement

Comment: It's back to giving me 636; It's reading from the entire table instead of just the project again. What I think I might try is creating a separate button just for `FinalExpenditure` so that instead of trying to figure out how many boxes are toggled, there's only one (if that makes sense).

Comment: It's a circular issue. We keep coming back to it. I have no idea how your forms are laid out, but the query isn't able to identify which project number to filter on. Look at [this](http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm) and see if it helps.

Comment: I see you never figured this issue out..What's the current state?

Comment: I think I figured out why it's not working. An empty row automatically gets added when one is filled; so technically, there all the checkboxes are never filled. I'm trying to modify the SQL to see if I can make it check that the year column isn't empty. It just didn't occur to me until now that this could be causing a problem.

Comment: Any empty row gets added (to what) when **what** gets filled?

Comment: An empty row gets added to the table when the one before it is filled. I edited the table in my original question to try and show this.

Comment: That shouldn't be difficult to accommodate for.. add something like `HAVING Year Is Not Null`

Comment: Hmmm. It's still not working... I don't know how to get it to read the right `ProjNo`.

Comment: That's been your problem the entire time. At one point you said it was working but it obviously wasn't. Did you even check the link I posted on how to reference fields on a form/sub form? That's the key to all of this

Comment: I looked at the link. Even if I reference it according to it, I'm still having problems.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
sql = "SELECT Sum(Amount) as Final From Expenditures " & _
"Where ProjNo = '" + Me.ProjNo + "' And Final = True Group by ProjNo"
```

For this:

```
"SELECT SUM(Amount) - SUM(IIF(Final,1,0)*Amount) as YetToConfirm, SUM(Amount) as Confirmed From Expenditures " & _
"Where ProjNo = '" + Me.ProjNo + "' Group by ProjNo"
```

**rs1** will return two values, the total value if all costs were confirmed in the `rs1!Confirmed`, and the value yet to confirm in `rs1!YetToConfirm`

Then here:

`Do While Not rs2.EOF
    rs2.Edit
    rs2!FinalExpenditure = rs1!Final
    rs2.Update
    rs2.MoveNext
Loop`

change it to:

`Do While Not rs2.EOF
    rs2.Edit
    rs2!FinalExpenditure = Iif(rs1!YetToConfirm = 0, rs1!Confirmed, 0)
    rs2.Update
    rs2.MoveNext
Loop`

Comment: When I try and run this, it tells me 'Run-Time Error 2085: Undefined function 'IFF' in expression' at `Set rs1=`.

Comment: Yea... my bad, function is IIF not IFF... I've updated the answer to correspond.

Comment: Hm... This leaves the `FinalExpenditures` field blank even if all the boxes are toggled.

Comment: What do `rs1!YetToConfirm`  and `rs1!Confirmed` return can you step through (F8) to this step `rs2!FinalExpenditure = Iif(rs1!YetToConfirm = 0, rs1!Confirmed, 0)`

Comment: It's not letting me do that. I set up a breakpoint, but it doesn't stop when I run it.

Comment: What if you set a breakpoint at `If rs1.RecordCount > 0 Then` what do `rs1.RecordCount`and `rs2.RecordCount` return

Comment: It still doesn't stop. Now - and I can't believe I didn't think of this sooner - could this be because an additional row automatically gets added when the last box is checked? Maybe that's causing a problem with it...

Answer (score 1):

One way to process this would be check using a subquery whether last year(verified using a dmax function) in each project has been checked in the final column, if this is true, get your sum of checked amounts, else dont calculate the sum.
I have modified your sql string to include this and I tested it against your given example to confirm its showing a sum of $300 or nothing.

```
SQL = ""
SQL = SQL & " SELECT Sum(Amount) as Final From Expenditures "
SQL = SQL & " Where ProjNo = '" & Me.ProjNo & "' And Final = True "
SQL = SQL & " And (SELECT Expenditures.Final FROM Expenditures where year = ( "
SQL = SQL & " DMax('Year','Expenditures','ProjNo= " & Chr(34) & Me.ProjNo & Chr(34) & "'))) = true "
SQL = SQL & " Group by ProjNo "
```